# _spPageContextInfo in modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx-extensions, modern-pages, applicationcustomizers

Using SPFx extension (application customizer) added JS files to all SharePoint pages (including modern pages), something like mentioned in below blog:

[Step by Step Procedure to Add a JS file to all pages in a SPFx Modern Pages using SharePoint Framework Extension](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/).

I am using some custom JavaScript logic which runs in almost all pages, I am using `_spPageContextInfo` object extensively, it works fine in classic pages.

In modern page I get `_spPageContextInfo` is undefined.

Are there any alternative ways I can get `_spPageContextInfo` object value using normal JavaScript in modern pages.

In SPFx we can use `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext` but not in JavaScript

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly you are fetching from `_spPageContextInfo` in your code? Maybe we can suggest you another way to get the same in SPFx.

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage,
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl,
_spPageContextInfo.listUrl,
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,
_spPageContextInfo.listID, are few objects

Comment: Are you not able to use `legacyPageContext` in your code?

Comment: You mean this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext ? No, get undefined error for pageContext in javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using below solutions:

**Solution 1**:

Use `legacyPageContext` to access the `pageContext` information:

```
// This is how you can access the page context info
this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext;

// Retreive current user display name 
this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext["userDisplayName"]);
```

**Source**: [Access _spPageContextInfo details in SharePoint Framework](https://medium.com/@rjesh/access-sppagecontextinfo-details-in-sharepoint-framework-8daa3479bf27) - Check the list of properties you can access using `legacyPageContext`.

**Solution 2**:

Use `_spPageContextInfo` under `window` object:

```
const pageContext: any = (window as any)._spPageContextInfo;
```

**Source**: [SPFx Extensions - Multi-Lingual Support](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/react-menu-footer-classic-modern/Documentation/Article.md#multi-lingual-support).

**Solution 3**:

1. Get the `pageContext` from `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext;`.
2. Push the whole object under `window` or `document` object.
3. Access it from `window` or `document`.

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me, thanks!!