# How to get current page URL in SharePoint page through web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, reactjs

I tried using the `window.location.href`, its not working when the webpart is deployed in the production environment

How to get the current page URL on the SharePoint web part?

Comment: Where are you using `window.location.href` in your code? Can you show the code sample you are using?

Comment: i using it on the method which is getting invoked compoenentDidMount method and its returning the diffrent url with some encoded number (not relevant to the page) in the production environment and how we can get the page title?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
var currentPageUrl = this.context.pageContext.site.serverRequestPath;
```

---

Also, as per the post [Get Page URL in SharePoint Framework (SPFx) - No JavaScript Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/717887/get-page-url-in-sharepoint-framework-spfx-no-javas.html),

You should be able to get the current page URL using `window.location.href`:

Code:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

You can get the current site page item ID using below:

```
this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext["pageItemId"])
```

Using this item ID and SharePoint REST API/PnP JS, you can get all the page details from site pages library.

Comment: serverRequestPath always giving 
: 
"/_layouts/15/webpart.aspx" but it should give the complete url which is not happening

Comment: window.location.href is giving the wrong url https://abcportal-appb7d518ccc3cb4e2faeeb0d042fc7b921.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/webpart.aspx?sw=bypass     but it should give the page url which is diffrent as you knew.

Comment: Did you check the value of `serverRequestPath` after deploying the SPFx web part to app catalog and by adding to actual site page? If you are debugging it on SharePoint workbench, it will return `/_layouts/15/webpart.aspx` as expected.

Comment: Its returning /_layouts/15/webpart.aspx after the deployment but that should not be in the case

Comment: Any Idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Did you `--ship` while bundling and packaging solution?

Comment: yes i am using gulp bundle --ship

Comment: any idea how to get the GUID for the current page ? or any way to get the ID of current page so i can traverse the site pages list and get the page title and page link from there? @Ganesh Sanap

Comment: Can you try using this as well: `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext["serverRequestPath"]`?

Comment: You can find the page related details under context: `this.context.pageContext` like: `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext["pageItemId"])` Or using `_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId`. check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273370/sppagecontextinfo-in-modern-pages

Comment: this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext["pageItemId"]) works out and even in window.location.href url was having id in the url. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the page id in `componentDidMount` by using `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext["pageItemId"])` and use this method to get the page details:

```
public async getPageDetails(){
    let web = new Web(this.props.absoluteUrl + "/../siteName");  
  
    let pages = await  web.lists.getByTitle("Site Pages").items.select("Title,GUID,ID,FileRef, EncodedAbsUrl").getAll().then((items: any[])=>{
      console.log('items',items);
      items.forEach((item)=>{
        if(item.Id==this.pageId && item.ID==this.pageId)
        {
           console.log('page id match',item);
           this.title=item.Title;
           this.siteUrl=item.EncodedAbsUrl;
        }
      });
     });
  }**
```

and you can use title, siteUrl wherever its required.